# Cannot run Cisco PacketTracer 7.0 on Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: cisco

I run 'packettracer' with and without `sudo` but cannot run it. always show this in terminal:

[image]

And when I try to run it from menu it shows `packettracer 7 is not found`.

I use Kubuntu 17.04.

Comment: You might be missing a setting behind "packettracer" and the program was not made such it would check on that input. Do a `packettracer --help` and see if it shows a mandatory option (probably you need to supply a NIC/device name or IP).

Comment: I run 'packettracer --help' but it shows same thing.

Comment: yeh, same result for 18.04 -- doesn't run.